# An Exam Question (Verbs)

Tags: exam-questions

He is a doctor. He visits/serves his patients at 4 o'clock.
Visit or serve?
Which verb is correct?

(I mean, there are two verbs 'visit and serve'. The doctor ............ his patients at 4 o'clock. I have to use one of these verbs. Which one?)

Comment: Can you explain what kind of word you are looking for?  "Visit" and "serve" mean very different things.  Is the doctor going to the patients, or are the patients coming to the doctor, or something else?

Comment: IMHO, doctors don't "serve" patients at specific time points, but sometimes do "visit" them. We can say that a doctor served his patients for 20 years, but that would reflect the nature of his work and his dedication, not some function executed at specific points in time.

Comment: @CopperKettle I think the OP is asking which verb to use for a regular ***ward round***.

Comment: It's idle speculation for us to keep posting comments about what we *think* OP's intended context might be. The question is currently Unclear.

Comment: Voting to leave open. I don't see what the confusion is. It's visit. Done, next question.

Comment: I did not know the site served, or is that visited, as a place for people to ask exam or homework questions without indicating what they think the answer is and why.

Answer (score 4):

Normally a doctor "sees" a patient if they come to his place of work. A doctor "visits" a patient if the doctor travels to where the patient is.